# Get morphFrom on laravel polymorphic relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I am using [laravel polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

My `Comment.php` class

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body', 'commentable_id', 'commentable_type'];

    /**
     * Get the owning commentable model.
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }    

    // public function commentFrom()
    // {
    //   return where it commented from.
    // }
}
```

**What I want:** I want all comment with where it commented (post/video) from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `with('commentable')` to all the comments and its `post` or `video`:

```php
Comment::with('commentable')->get()
```

Comment: and where the `post` and the `video` relations?

Comment: can you complete the where condition too?

Comment: @hasan05 do u want to get the comment that have video or post?

Comment: I want to get all comment with either its video or post.

Comment: @hasan05 sorry, I misunderstanded, I have changed the code to ploymorphic one-to-many

Comment: while i tried it didn't get data. may be i misunderstand or didnt check properly. btw thanks a lot.